# How to join two pieces of sheet metal?

Tags: joints, sheet-metal

I have a piece of sheet metal flashing I would like to extend by about 6". Due to its installation, it would be impractical to remove it and put a new piece that is of the right size, so a functional work-around might be to seam another piece to it.

What is a good way to join two pieces of sheet metal? Can I lap them by a couple of inches and then use some kind of fastener (rivet?) every few inches along the seam?

Comment: Picture? Size? What is it on top of?

Comment: This is a very general question. Imaginr two pieces of 2x2 sheet metal that you want to join to form a 2x4 piece

Comment: It's aluminum flashing like you would use for roofing, windows etc

Comment: *This is a very general question.* That's actually the problem. Tell me you want to connect two heavy sheets of steel and I might say weld them. Two sheets of aluminum maybe not. Attaching when one is already installed limits options more, *depending on where it is installed*, etc.

Comment: Off a flat roof. Don't complicate things. You have enough info. Shouldn't require welding

Comment: So you (probably, but you're carefully avoiding giving enough detail to answer) need it to be watertight - such details matter. And likely the piece that's in place can't be bent to form a proper lock-seam, but you haven't provided a picture.

Comment: The extending piece will be tucked under. Just imagine I have two pieces of 2x2 of really skinny aluminum sheet metal and need to join it to be 2x4. It's a low duty application.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

#### Pop Rivets

The easiest way would be with a pop riveter.

- Clamp the two pieces together.  Drill a hole for the rivet.  Install one rivet.
- Repeat this for a rivet at the other end.
- Drill all the inbetween holes.
- Run a strip of thin cardboard between the sheets from the uphill side to get out any shavings you missed.
- Rivet the remaining holes.

I suggest practicing on scrap.  A pop rivet has one side that doesn't look bad, but isn't pretty from the other side.

---

#### Epoxy

A second easy way is with epoxy.  Read the labels and get one matched to your metal.

Epoxy needs **clean** metal to bond to.  It also helps if it has some tooth.

- Do a dry run so that you know your clamping system works.  You can test it by clamping with a few strips of paper between the sheets.  If you can pull out any of the sheets, you need to redesign.
- Mark the limits of where you want the pieces to align with a scratch using a utility blade.  You do not want to go through the paint or galvanizing if present.
- use a 100 grit sanding sponge to rough up the surface and take off the shine.
- wash once with tri sodium phosphate, 1 tablespoon in a quart of HOT water.
- Rinse with clean water.
- Allow to dry.
- Wipe with an acetone soaked cloth.  (Caution moderately toxic and very explosive fumes.)
- Let dry.  (Won't be long)
- Mix up your glue.  **DO THE FULL MIXING TIME**
- Apply your glue in a thin layer to both surfaces.  A wood coffee stir stick works well as an applicator.
- Clamp the pieces together.
- Remove any glue that squeezes out.

You can try using construction adhesive meant for non porous surfaces.  This is hard to squeeze flat for a short joint, but it may be more tolerant of temperature changes or outdoor use.

Comment: Yep, I think rivet is it

Comment: You missed a sure win: combine epoxy and pop rivets! +1